# How to parse a line using Parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm using the parsing library Parsec to parse some text.
I simply need to parse lines, which are strings of arbitrary characters, ending with a '\n' or an eof when its at the end of the string.
When calling `parseHS'` I get the complaint that `Exception: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string.`.

```
parseHS' :: String -> Either ParseError [String]
parseHS' input = parse hsFile' "(unknown)" input

hsFile' :: GenParser Char st [String]
hsFile' = do
    many1 line

line :: GenParser Char st String
line = do
    result <- many (noneOf "\n")
    optional newline
    return result
```

How could this be achieved correctly?

Comment: This seems correct, and the exception doesn't make much sense since `noneOf` doesn't accept an empty string. Are you sure you don't have a `many line` somewhere else in your code ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tarmil. Yes, I do have a many1 line one level above this. That's all.

Comment: Answer updated to include a full code example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, if you only need to split the input by lines, you could use `lines`.

`sepEndBy` in Parsec does what you want - splits input into a list of parsed entities separated by a given separator, optionally ending with it or eof.

Your grammar for `line` permits the parser to produce a never-ending stream of lines for any input. This can be resolved by making the decision about newline externally to line:

```
hsFile' = do
        x <- line
        xs <- many $ do
                newline
                line
        eof
        return (x:xs)

line = many $ noneOf "\n"
```

This one will produce a empty line at the end in case the file ends with newline.

Answer (score 6):

If you apply `many` (or `many1`) to a parser that accepts (among others) the empty string, you have an ambiguous grammar. The empty string could be recognized arbitrarily often, resulting in different parse trees.

In this case, `line` accepts the empty string, and `many1` is implemented in terms of `many`, so this triggers the exception. The solution in your situation is probably to make sure that `line` always consumes at least one character.

Answer (score 2):

It's overkill to use a parser for this, since you've no restriction on the content of the lines. There's a library function, `lines`, that achieves what you're asking with considerably less fuss.

Example:

```
lines "Hello there\neveryone,\nhere are some lines,"
> ["Hello there", "everyone,", "here are some lines,"]
```

If the lines have some structure, you should code that first instead of trying to chop the string up - bottom up is the best way to write recursive descent parsers.